# extract the last line from curl progress output into a variable

Tags: bash, curl

I have a file `output.txt` containing a cURL progress output like

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  0  490M    0     0    0  208k      0   248k  0:33:43 --:--:--  0:33:43  248k
  0  490M    0     0    0  256k      0   157k  0:53:11  0:00:01  0:53:10  157k
  0  490M    0     0    0  368k      0   140k  0:59:49  0:00:02  0:59:47  140k
  3  490M    0     0    3 19.5M      0   155k  0:53:50  0:02:08  0:51:42  153k
  3  490M    0     0    3 19.6M      0   154k  0:54:05  0:02:09  0:51:56  141k
  4  490M    0     0    4 19.7M      0   154k  0:54:06  0:02:10  0:51:56  120k
```

I would ONLY like to extract the last line. When I do:

```
LASTLINE=$(tail -n1 output.txt)
```

It is apparent that even tho

```
echo $LASTLINE
```

shows the last line, it contains everything as evidence by:

```
echo "${#LASTLINE}"
```

which shows `709`, the count of the number of characters, but the last line should only have 79 characters. I understand this is something about buffers. What is going on?

Comment: What is `${#LASTLINE}` and what do you expect it to be?

Comment: (Also, don't use ALLCAPS for your own variables. See [Correct bash and shell script variable capitalization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673055/correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization) for details)

Comment: it should be `4  490M    0     0    4 19.7M      0   154k  0:54:06  0:02:10  0:51:56  120k
`

Comment: `${#LASTLINE}` should just be a number.

Comment: Unable to duplicate, btw. `foo=$(tail -n1 output.txt) && echo "${#foo}"` gives me 78.

Comment: Perhaps there are some trailing or in beetween non printable characters in the file. Check it with `hexdump` or `od`.

Comment: Thanks, that totally was the case, copy and pasting it into stackoverflow fixed it so it could not reproduce. thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have carriage returns in that file. Get rid of everything preceding and including the last one using sed:

```
LASTLINE=$(sed '$!d;s/.*\r//' output.txt)
```